# github uploading project issue

Tags: github

I created a github new repository first in github webpage and then I opened Git Bash to upload folders to this repository. I first used `$cd f:` and `$ git clone git@github.com:username/project name.git` to create a folder(with a initial .git folder and a README file in it) in f disk. Then, I used `$cd f:\project name` to switch to the current folder. After that, I copied all my project folders to my project name folder in f disk. Finally, I used the following four lines to upload all my project folders to github:

```
$git add .
$git remote rm origin
$git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project name.git
$git push -u origin master
```

After I entered the passphrase, Git Bash just showed everything up-to-date. But I refreshed my github repository page, there is nothing but the initial README file. Could someone tell me what the matter is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't commit after your `git add`.

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

That is why git considered there was nothing to push: you HEAD was still the same than your remote origin cloned repo.

See [Git Basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States):

[image: git three stages]

Your `git add` updating the staging area (index), but only a `git commit` will update your git directory.

Comment: So what's the 'first commit' used for? And if I make changes to my local project files, how should I update it in github? Do I just need the last four git bash lines mentioned in my question?

Comment: @chaonextdoor you need first to commit your changes (that you have added to the index), before pushing them to GitHub (which will update those file on GitHub). Add "`git commit`" after your `git add` and before your three other steps.